# Javascript - Difference between using + and , when joining strings/variables?

Tags: javascript, performance

For example, what is the difference between these two? Don't they print out the same thing?

```
var myName = "Example"

console.log("My name is " + myName);

console.log("My name is", myName);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it's really much of a difference https://github.com/DeveloperToolsWG/console-object/blob/master/api.md#consolelogobject--object-

Comment: This is more of the differences of `console.log` using a comma to separate them will log them as separate objects, `+` will concatenate/add them (and probably end up being a string). but you can use `sprintf`-like formatters in `console.log`: `console.log("My name is %s", "Example");`

Comment: The difference appears when you want to include an object, or another non-string. Of course, it all depends on the browser too, since there are no standards for console

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the example you gave the two forms will produce the same output. However, this is behavior specific to `console.log` and you cannot in general join two strings using a comma.

Answer (score 0):

`+` *concatenates* a string (i.e. combines them). In your first example, `console.log` takes one argument: `"My name is " + myName` as a single combined string. In your second example, `console.log` takes two arguments: `"My name is"` and `myName`, as separate strings.